# How to run the server simultaneously with the client in a nodeJS application using concurently when the files are in different folders

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm

My project is split into 2 folders
client and server
in the client folder the usual
`react-create-app package.json`
in sever folder
`package.json` with trace script

```
scripts: {
 start: node app.js
server: nodemon app.js
}
```

how can I run the script through npm start to run both the backend and the frontend at the same time

```
client
  -app.js
  -package.json
server
  -app.js
  -package.json
```

I found a solution that you can start from the server folder as follows

```
dev: "concurently" npm run server "" npm run client "
```

but how to start if package.json is in different folders

Comment: relative paths to point to the other directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your client/front-end and server/back-end folders are separated in the root directory, you can run both the front-end and back-end servers together at the same time using `concurrently`. A few things need to be done before this is possible:

1. CD into your root directory
2. `npm init -y` (enter)
3. `touch .gitignore` (enter)
4. Add `/node_modules` to the `.gitignore` file
5. `npm install concurrently nodemon --save-dev` (enter)
6. Install all your backend **server** dependencies in the root directory
7. Add the three scripts below to your root `package.json`:

```js
"scripts": {
  "server": "nodemon --quiet server",
  "client": "npm start --prefix client",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
},
```

*Both the `client` and `backend` scripts are ran together by the `dev` script from the root directory when the `npm run dev` command is executed in the terminal. The `dev` script traverses both the client and server directories, locates the directories index.js file, and then runs each server.*

*Your server/back-end directory doesn't need scripts, a `package.json` or any `node_modules` as they will be available globally from the root directory.*

> ```
> client
>   -index.js (index.js file in react is ran before app.js)
>   -package.json
> server
>   -app.js <-- Rename to index.js
>   -package.json <-- Remove package.json
> ```

8. CD into your client/front-end directory
9. Add this `start` script to your client `package.json`:

```js
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
},
```

10. Run your server/back-end and client/front-end at the same time by CD'ing into your root directory and executing `npm run dev` (enter)

This is what your directories will look like:

```
root
  client
    -index.js
    -package.json
    -/node_modules
  server
    -index.js
-package.json
-/node_modules
```

*This directory setup is better for heroku deployment.*